# state management on page refresh/add to cart functionality angular 9

Tags: angular

I am wondering how to persist cart objects when user refresh the page.
Situation: I have a add to cart functionality  which can be accessible/visible from many components.
I need to maintain cart objects while going one page to another(SPA- routing will be used) and also on page refresh.
Can any one suggest best approach for that.
Note: objects added in cart may consist many key-value data that is needed on cart component(suggestions on this will be also a addition)
Tech stack: angular 9
condition: user is not logged in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like a job for cookies... did using them cause some sort of issue?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to save them in a DB.
but if you dont have any backend you can add on localstorage or sessionStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(this.itemsInCart));
this.itemsInCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'));
```

you can find some info here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-introduction-localstorage-sessionstorage